# Why my Tab Layout and Toolbar are showing like this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-tablelayout

As you can see in the image. These two are not aligned properly. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

My toolbar is in Coordinator Layout in app_bar_main.xml and my Tab Layout is in fragment_main. I didn't add the tab layout in coordinator layout because I don't want to show it in all my views, just in my fragment main file.

My code in app_bar_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code in fragment_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_1">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

Can you tell what I am doing wrong?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWMAJ.jpg)

Comment: Set _elevation_ 0 for toolbar in style

Comment: elevation is 0 @PiyushGupta.

Comment: check my code. @PiyushGupta

Comment: @AndroidGeek please refresh.

Answer (score 0):

For those who were not able to solve this.

I was able to solve it through an approach.

I added the above code in Main Activity and then set the visibility of tablayout and Toolbar in other fragments as GONE and in fragment which I want it to enable as VISIBLE.

To set visibility as gone you do:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_pager_1);
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And to set it as visible just replace GONE with VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/empty_area"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drop_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The other way, as you mentioned is to put the tab layout inside the AppBarLayout in app_bar_main.xml